# Django Import Custom Module to Views.py

Tags: python, django

We have this folder structure:

```
django_app
├── __init__.py
├── views.py
├── bot_funcs
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bot.py
```

Both `django_app` and `bot_funcs` have blank `__init__.py` files.

We are attempting to import bot.py into views.py. We have tried every combination we can think of, and assumed something like this would work:

```
from .bot_funcs import bot
```

This results in a 500 server error on our website and this traceback in Spyder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-937d4612431c>", line 1, in <module>
    from .bot_funcs import bot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.bot_funcs'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I think this traceback is a red herring, because other imports in views.py (e.g. `from .models import Feedback`) return the same traceback, but work properly on the website.

What is the best way to import from a folder located in the app folder, and why are the usual import methods not working?

Comment: from app_name.bot_funcs import bot

Comment: that has the same issue, unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried this: from bot_funcs import bot

Comment: yes, same issue with that one